# Javascript Match two strings with atleast n number of characters

Tags: javascript

I want to match to strings for at least n number of characters, say 3.

For example If I have two words, I want to return true if two words have a common substring of 3 characters

ie, If I match  California and Unical, I want to get true, since both have "Cal" as a common string.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findCommonSubstring(s1, s2, n) {

    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();
    var min = s1.length < s2.length ? s1 : s2;
    var max = min == s1 ? s2 : s1;

    if(n <= 0 || n > min.length) {
        return false;
    }

    var substring;
    for(var i=0; i<=min.length-n; i++) {
        if(max.indexOf((substring = min.substring(i, i+n))) > -1) {
            return substring;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Call:

```
alert(findCommonSubstring("California", "Unical", 3));​
```

Prints:

```
cal
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2kUDw/5/)

Comment: the function should take into account the occasion when the user will use n<=0 and return false

Comment: @MIrrorMirror If the user uses `n<=0`, the `for` loop simply won't have any iteration and the function will then return `false`.

Comment: @sp00m no it doesn't, i tested it myself in your demo, it seemly returns an empty string. here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/2kUDw/3/

Comment: @MIrrorMirror Oops, you was right, I edited my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function matchStrings(s1, s2, charnum) {
    var found = false;
    var i = 0;
    if ( charnum>0 && charnum<s2.length ) {
        s1=s1.toLowerCase();
        s2=s2.toLowerCase();
        for (i=0; i<=s2.length - charnum; i++) {
            if ( s1.indexOf(s2.substr(i, charnum)) > -1 ) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: when `i = 1`, this function returns `true` if the first character of `s2` if found in `s1`?

Comment: also false. it checks only if the first charnum characters are found in s1

Comment: instead of s2.substr(i, charnum) i guess you mean s2.substr(i, i+charnum) ?

Comment: no, it's correct: it's substr(start, length), you are confusing it with substring(initialpos, lastpos)

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(first,second,nl)
{
    first=first.toLowerCase();
    second=second.toLowerCase();

   if(first.length>second.length)
   {
       var len=first.length ;
   }
   else
   {
       var len=second.length;
       var t=first;
       first=second;
       second=t;
   }

   //var len=first.length>second.length?first.length:second.length;

   var count=0;
   while(len>=nl)
   {
       str=first.substr(count,nl);
       if(second.indexOf(str)!=-1)
       {
           return str;
           break;
       }
       count++;
       len--;
   }
   return false;        
}
 alert(test('Cal','unicbbl',4))  
 alert(test('California','unicali',3));
 alert(test('California','unicali',4));
[test here][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/tuMRg/5/
```

Comment: the solution is wrong. proof here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tuMRg/3/ despite the fact the two strings don't have a common substring of 4 chars, it returns "l".

Comment: In this case you have to fix in which string you want to search and what string to be searched,also the number of characters should be less than the string length which is to be searched.

Answer (score 0):

Following is quite complicated, but this is a good choice if you search string from large content. It starts by filtering possible matches and then tests those possibilities.

```
var atLeastMatch = function(search, content, atLeast) {
    var search = search,
        content = content,
        regex = new RegExp('[' + search + ']{' + atLeast + ',}', "i", "g"),
        possibleMatches = content.match(regex);

    for (var i = 0, j = possibleMatches.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (possibleMatches[i].length > atLeast) {
            for (var k = 0, l = possibleMatches[i].length - atLeast; k <= l; k++) {
                if ((new RegExp(possibleMatches[i].slice(k, k + atLeast), "i")).test(search)) {
                    return true;
                }

            }

        } else {
            if ((new RegExp(possibleMatches[i], "i")).test(search)) {
                return true;
            }

        }

    }

    return false;

}

console.log(atLeastMatch('California', 'Unical', 3));
```